# Show that if $p$ is an odd prime, then the congruence $x^2\equiv1\pmod{p^{\alpha}}$ has only two solutions, $x\equiv1,x\equiv-1\pmod{p^{\alpha}}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

> Show that if $p$ is an odd prime, then the congruence $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{p^{\alpha}}$ has only two solutions, which are $x \equiv 1, x \equiv -1 \pmod{p^{\alpha}}$.

Clearly $x \equiv 1, x \equiv - 1 \pmod{p^{\alpha}}$ are solutions. We'll show that there are no other solutions. Suppose that $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{p^{\alpha}}$. Then

$$
\begin{align}
x^2-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p^{\alpha}} &\Longleftrightarrow (x+1)(x-1) \equiv 0 \pmod{p^{\alpha}} \\
&\Longrightarrow p^{\alpha} \mid (x+1)(x-1) \\
&\Longrightarrow p \mid (x+1)(x-1)
\end{align}
$$

By Euclid's Lemma, if a prime divides a product $ab$, then it must divide either $a$ or $b$. So $p \mid (x+1)$ or $p \mid (x-1)$. Suppose $p \mid x + 1$. Since $x +1$ and $x-1$ differ by a factor of $2$ and $p > 2$ ($p$ odd), it follows that $\gcd(p^{\alpha},x-1) = 1$. Thus $p^{\alpha} \mid x + 1 \Longrightarrow x \equiv -1 \pmod{p^{\alpha}}$. Similarly, if $p \mid (x-1)$, then $\gcd(p^{\alpha},x+1) = 1 \Longrightarrow p^{\alpha} \mid (x-1) \Longrightarrow x \equiv 1 \pmod{p^{\alpha}} \text{. } \Box$

Is my proof correct? Criticism appreciated.

Comment: Yep, this is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Tim Raczkowski Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I would add a bit of detail. By Euclid's Lemma, $p$ divides $x-1$ or $p$ divides $x+1$. Suppose $p$ divides $x-1$. Argue that since $p$ is odd, $p$ cannot divide $x+1$. So $p^\alpha$ and $x+1$ are relatively prime. It follows that $p^\alpha$ divides $x-1$. Now do the same for the case $p$ divides $x+1$.

Comment: See also this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1241300/if-x2-equiv-y2-pmod-pr-where-p-is-an-odd-prime-not-dividing-x-or

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you, I changed my answer according to your suggestion.

Comment: You are welcome.  I would start by saying that it is obvious that $x\equiv 1\pmod{p^\alpha}$ and $x\equiv -1\pmod{p^\alpha}$ are solutions, and that they are distinct modulo $p^\alpha$. We show that there are no other solutions. Suppose that $x^2\equiv 1\pmod{p^\alpha}$. Then $(x-1)(x+1)\equiv \dots$.

Comment: In your revised solution, you don't want to  say that $p^\alpha$ does not divide $x-1$, for that does not help, the relevant thing is that $x-1$ and $p^\alpha$ are relatively prime.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you for the suggestions.  To address your most recent comment, this is pretty much the fundamental theorem of arithmetic right? $(a,b) = 1$ and $a \mid bc \Longrightarrow a \mid c.$

Comment: The FTA follows relatively quickly from the assertion, but it is more often called Euclid's Lemma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO there is something missing.  Your last implication says, in effect, that if $p\mid x-1$ then $p^\alpha\mid x-1$, which is certainly not true.

The point you need to make (earlier in the proof) is this: since $x+1$ and $x-1$ differ by $2$, they cannot both be multiples of $p$ (because $p$ is greater than $2$).  Therefore, the $p^\alpha$ which is a factor of $(x-1)(x+1)$ must be entirely a factor of $x-1$, or entirely a factor of $x+1$.

Comment: Thank you, I changed my answer according to the suggestions of you and André Nicolas.